# Homomorphism, eigenvalues and geometric multiplicity.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f:V \rightarrow V$ be an endomorphism, with $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$.

### Statement 1:

> If for some vector $v \in V$, the set $S=\{v,f(v),f^2(v),\dots,f^{n-1}(v)\}$ is >linearly independent, then $\forall \lambda_{0}$ eigenvalue of $f$ we have >$\dim[V_{1}(\lambda_{0})]=1$.

Here, $V_{1}(\lambda_{0})$ is the set of eigenvectors associated to $\lambda_{0}$.

This exercise has a second part.

### Statement 2:

> If $f$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then $\exists u\in V-\{0\}$ that the set
>   $S'=\{u,f(u),f^2(u),\dots,f^{n-1}(u)\}$ is linearly independent.

In the course we haven't studied canonical Jordan forms and these statements must be proved with the characterisation theorems of diagonalisation.

I can't imagine a solution and the only thing I can realise is that the sets $S$ and $S'$ are bases of V. I don't know if it could be useful.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Suppose $f(v)= \lambda_0 v,$ then $f^2(v)= \lambda_0 ^2 v$ and so on. What can you say about $\lambda_0 , \lambda_0 ^2 , \dots , \lambda_0 ^ n ?$

Comment: @Itay4 I don't follow you, sorry. Could you develop a bit more, please?

Answer (score 1):

These are general indications, not a full solution :

Statement 1 : If $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$, write $x=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_kf^k (v)$ and $f(x)=\lambda x = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \lambda a_k f^k(v)$, but also $f(x) =\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k f^{k+1}(v)$.  Compare the two writings of $f(x)$.

Statement 2 : Consider $n$ eigenvectors $x_1,...,x_n$ with distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$. What can you say about $u := \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ ?

Comment: I think I can conclude the second part. Starting with the vector $u$, if we construct the set $\{u,f(u),f^{2}(u),\dots,f^{n-1}(u)\}$, this set must be linearly independet because $f$ is diagonizable.

Comment: Still, I don't know how to end the first part.

Comment: Why must it be linearly independent ? As for the first part, you know that $\{u,..., f^{n-1}(u)\}$ is a basis for $V$, so you can write $f^n(u)$ in it, and compare the two expressions for $f(x)$, knowing that you can identifiy coefficients since it's a basis.

Comment: Okay, I thought wrong. I'm again where I was.